# Using Information of objects from one class in function of a different class

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

so I'm very new to Python and trying to piece this together through YouTube and various websites. For an FPS game I play, I'm trying to come up with a DPS (Damage/Sec) calculation for various guns and their best-in-slot ammo (bis). I've listed every ammo out as an object under the Ammo class, as well as each weapon as an object in a Weapon class. Example:

```
class Ammo:
    def __init__(self, name, damage, pen, cost, caliber, bis):
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage
        self.pen = pen
        self.cost = cost
        self.caliber = caliber
        self.bis = bis

#   9x19 mm ammo    MP5/MPX/MP9

a7N31 = Ammo('7N31', 52, 39, 489, '9x19mm', True)
aAP63 = Ammo('AP 6.3', 52, 30, 327, '9x19mm', False)
a9GT = Ammo('Green Tracer', 58, 14, 70, '9x19mm', False)

#   12.7x55 mm ammo    ASh-12

aPS12 = Ammo('PS12', 115, 28, 361, "12.7x55mm", False)
aPS12A = Ammo('PS12A', 165, 10, 342, "12.7x55mm", False)
aPS12B = Ammo('PS12B', 102, 46, 603, "12.7x55mm", True)

#   7.62x51 mm ammo    SA-58/.308 MDR

aM62 = Ammo('M62', 79, 54, 469, "7.62x51mm", True)
aM80 = Ammo('M80', 80, 41, 200, "7.62x51mm", False)
aTPZ = Ammo('TPZ SP', 60, 36, 113, "7.62x51mm", False)


class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, name, rpm, caliber, gcost, bcost, recoil):
        self.name = name
        self.rpm = rpm
        self.caliber = caliber
        self.gcost = gcost
        self.bcost = bcost
        self.recoil = recoil

w0 = Weapon('ASh-12', 650, '12.7x55 mm', '~75,000 ₽', '~165,000 ₽', 128)
w1 = Weapon('MP9-N', 1100, '9x19 mm', '~23,000 ₽', '~101,000 ₽', 48)
w2 = Weapon('SA-58', 700, '7.62x51 mm', '~50,000 ₽', '~215,000 ₽', 63)
```

What I can't figure out is how to make a function that takes the Damage of the ammo marked Best-in-Slot (bis = True) and multiplies it by the Rounds per Minute (rpm) of a given weapon divided by 60. Ideally this function would account for the weapons caliber, automatically using the best ammo of that caliber.
I can't seem to find any information on using values of objects from one class for functions of a different class (if that's even what's going on here) and I'm honestly not sure if this is even the correct way to approach this. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I would suggest having a dictionary mapping caliber to BIS ammo for that caliber. Then it's a trivial lookup. Or you could have a class method on `Ammo` to expose it, maybe work towards something like `def dps(self): return self.rpm * Ammo.best_for_caliber(self.caliber).damage / 60`.

Comment: Please describe the classes 'Ammo' and 'Weapon'. Add the relations between them as well, This will help us to get to the right implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```py
class Ammo:
    def __init__(self, name, damage, pen, cost, caliber, bis):
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage
        self.pen = pen
        self.cost = cost
        self.caliber = caliber
        self.bis = bis

#   9x19 mm ammo    MP5/MPX/MP9

a7N31 = Ammo('7N31', 52, 39, 489, '9x19mm', True)
aAP63 = Ammo('AP 6.3', 52, 30, 327, '9x19mm', False)
a9GT = Ammo('Green Tracer', 58, 14, 70, '9x19mm', False)

#   12.7x55 mm ammo    ASh-12

aPS12 = Ammo('PS12', 115, 28, 361, "12.7x55mm", False)
aPS12A = Ammo('PS12A', 165, 10, 342, "12.7x55mm", False)
aPS12B = Ammo('PS12B', 102, 46, 603, "12.7x55mm", True)

#   7.62x51 mm ammo    SA-58/.308 MDR

aM62 = Ammo('M62', 79, 54, 469, "7.62x51mm", True)
aM80 = Ammo('M80', 80, 41, 200, "7.62x51mm", False)
aTPZ = Ammo('TPZ SP', 60, 36, 113, "7.62x51mm", False)

class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, name, rpm, caliber, gcost, bcost, recoil):
        self.name = name
        self.rpm = rpm
        self.caliber = caliber
        self.gcost = gcost
        self.bcost = bcost
        self.recoil = recoil
    
    def find_bis(self, ammo_list):
        for ammo in ammo_list:
            if ammo.caliber == self.caliber and ammo.bis is True:
                return ammo
        return None
    
    def bis_rpm(self, ammo_list):
        bis = self.find_bis(ammo_list)
        if bis is None:
            return None
        return bis.damage * self.rpm / 60

w0 = Weapon('ASh-12', 650, '12.7x55mm', '~75,000 ₽', '~165,000 ₽', 128)
w1 = Weapon('MP9-N', 1100, '9x19mm', '~23,000 ₽', '~101,000 ₽', 48)
w2 = Weapon('SA-58', 700, '7.62x51mm', '~50,000 ₽', '~215,000 ₽', 63)

ammos = [a7N31, aAP63, a9GT, aPS12, aPS12A, aPS12B, aM62, aM80, aTPZ]

print(w0.find_bis(ammos).name, w0.bis_rpm(ammos))
print(w1.find_bis(ammos).name, w1.bis_rpm(ammos))
print(w2.find_bis(ammos).name, w2.bis_rpm(ammos))
```

Output:

```
PS12B 1105.0
7N31 953.3333333333334
M62 921.6666666666666
```

I made a list of all your ammos.

There are smarter ways to pack them (like making a dictionary) but that's just to show you the idea.

I also fixed a typo in the caliber (not the same between ammos and weapons in your original code, with a space difference).

Comment: This is brilliant and exactly what I needed. It took me a second to figure out what you meant about the caliber typo, which caused some confusion, but once I understood and made the adjustment it worked perfectly. I'm looking into Dictionaries now, but I'm not sure how their use would be an improvement over your solution. Is there some benefit I'm missing? Regardless, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. About the dictionaries, suppose instead of a basic list you stored your ammo objects in a dict where keys are the value of the caliber (values would be a list of ammos of that caliber). This means your weapon could fetch directly a list of ammos of compatible caliber and only look for bis in this list. This is one idea for optimizing the number of operations you will have to perform. Have fun learning python.